# Sine approximation error in Java

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

I'm a bit annoyed with a method I wrote to approximate sine function in Java. Here it is, it's based on Taylor's series.

```
  static double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
  static double eps = 0.0000000000000000001;

  static void sin(double x) {
    x = x % (2 * PI);
    double term = 1.0;
    double res  = 0.0;

    for (int i = 1; term > eps; i++) {
        term = term * (x / i);
        if (i % 4 == 1) res += term;
        if (i % 4 == 3) res -= term;
    }
  System.out.println(sum);
 }
```

For little values, I got very good approximation of sine, but for large values (e.g pow(10,22)), results seems very very wrong.

Here are the results :

```
 sin(pow(10,22)) // 0.8740280612007599
 Math.sin(pow(10,22)) // -0.8522008497671888
```

Does someone have an idea ? Thank you !

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be reassured that the Java `sin` function will be off too.

You problem is that the Taylor expansion for `sin` has a small radius of convergence and convergence is slow even if you're within that radius.

There are floating point considerations too: a floating point `double` gives you about 15 significant figures of accuracy.

So for large arguments for `sin`, the accuracy will deteriorate significantly especially given that `sin` is a *periodic* function:

`sin(x + 2 * pi * n) = sin(x)` for any integer `n`.

Comment: I thought `x = x % (2 * PI);` would avoid such accuracy loss (even if it's an approximate value of the parameter). Is there any way to reduce this ?

Comment: Nope. The initial `x` will already be too approximate. You can't use large floating point arguments with periodic functions. That's life I'm afraid. Good question though. I'm surprised nobody else has upvoted it.

Comment: Thank you ! I'll take a look for another method (some friends and me are writing a new language at school. We have to implement a Math class !). If you have any useful reference.. ;)

Comment: @Bathsheba Why " accuracy will deteriorate significantly especially given that sin is a periodic function"? What is special about periodic functions regarding accuracy?

Comment: Because as floating point numbers get larger, so do the "gaps" between them.

Comment: Did i get it right that the return value for 

Math.sin(pow(10,22)) // -0.8522008497671888

is wrong? and the approximation 0.8740280612007599 is the correct return value

Comment: Nope. The closest floating point number to 1e23 is 99999999999999991611392. You could use your favourite arbitrary precision decimal library to transform 1e23 to a number between -pi and pi by subtracting an integral number of 2 * pi, and compute the sin of that.

Comment: According to the equation given above this must be true 

Math.sin(x) == Math.sin(x % (2*PI)) 

but if x eqals pow(10,22) the values have different signs, which can not be justified by issue of accuracy

Comment: I don't think you understand the crux of the argument. Do consider reading up on floating point precision.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I am either a java or a math expert. I was just interested to know if the approximation is correct or not?

Comment: Nope, because the distance between floating point numbers in the 1e23 region is larger than 2 * pi, the result ought to be regarded as arbitrary.

Comment: @Bathsheba Sorry I don't get your answer above. You reply: "Because as floating point numbers get larger, so do the gaps between them" for my question: "What is special about periodic functions regarding accuracy". What is the relation between floating point gaps and periodic functions?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is incorrect for big numbers because you accumulate a lot of rounding errors due to `double` presentation. When the number is big, then your `for` loop will iterate a lot before the `term` becomes smaller than epsilon. In each iteration, a rounding error is accumulated. The result is a very big error in the final value. Read some nice reference on "Numerical Analysis". Anyway, Tylor's series approximate `sin` near 0, by definition. So, it is normal not to be correct for very big numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The difference actually has nothing to do with the radius of convergence of the Taylor Series and has to do with double precision not being accurate enough to hold the precision required for such big numbers.  The radius of the Taylor series for the sine function is infinity.

10^22 is approximately 2^73.  Since the mantissa for a double precision number is 52 bits, consecutive values that can be stored with double precision format will be 2^21 apart from each other.  Since an evaluation of the sine function requires more resolution than that, you won't be able to reliably get an answer.